# What is the idea behind AWS-Specific Parameter Types?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

During my foray into Cloudformation I came across the AWS-Specific Parameter Types which can be used in the parameter section.
But I somehow cant grasp completely the idea behind these constructs.
For me Parameter have a specific value I want to pass on when creating a resource.

What is the point of `AWS::EC2::Instance::Id` or `List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>`?

As far as I understood it's a kind of pre-check of sorts...

When would it make sense to use these AWS-Specific Parameter Types?

Thank you in advance A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CloudFormation user interface uses these types to present a better experience, such as a **pull-down list**.

Then there is the ability to [Query for the latest Amazon Linux AMI IDs using AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/query-for-the-latest-amazon-linux-ami-ids-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/) by using:

```
AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>
```

Comment: Merci, does that mean if I don’t use the console but do everything via templates and have applied mapping it makes no real sense to use the specific parameters?

Comment: Most probably yes, except for use-cases like the Parameter Store above where CloudFormation substitutes values.